# Where can I find some fun Excel sample data to download?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Are there any web applications out there that offer free Excel sample data utilizing fun topics like perhaps Star Wars characters?

Comment: What do you mean by "Excel sample data"?  [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) has many datasets made available for data science projects (including some Star Wars-related ones).

Comment: @BrenBarn, can those datasets be imported into an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Many of them are CSV files so yes, you could load them into a spreadsheet.

Comment: @BrenBarn, excellent! Please post as answer, I will check it out this weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kaggle is a website for data science competitions.  They have many [datasets](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets) available for use.  You generally must create a Kaggle account to get the data, but doing so is free.  Many of the datasets are available as CSV files, which you could load into Excel.  They're not designed for use in Excel, though, but rather for use with machine-learning libraries and programming tools (e.g., Scikit Learn), so some may be difficult to use in Excel depending on the nature of the data.  There are a few Star Wars related datasets, including for instance [this one](https://www.kaggle.com/xvivancos/star-wars-movie-scripts) that has dialogue from the movies.